Eclipse 2024-12 unable to start in Windows after update
I installed updates to my Eclipse installation, and once again, it will not start. Trying to avoid the tedium of doing a fresh install and restoring all my plugins and customisations, I have been trying to research solutions. Eventually I found an SO answer that recommended starting Eclipse with -Console and -ConsoleLog. So now I have an almost 500 line log file. Searching through it, the nub of the problem seems to be loading some critical modules.
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.vector
Dec 17, 2024 2:33:31 PM org.apache.aries.spifly.BaseActivator log
INFO: Registered provider org.slf4j.simple.SimpleServiceProvider of service org.slf4j.spi.SLF4JServiceProvider in bundle slf4j.simple
!SESSION 2024-12-17 14:33:23.006 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.34.0.20241128-0756
java.version=21.0.3
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_AU
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product -console -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.cbi.targetplatform 4 0 2024-12-17 14:33:32.443
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.cbi.targetplatform [304]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.xtext
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.xtext; bundle-version="2.25.0.v20210301-0843"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.xtext [1858]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.xtext.util; visibility:="reexport"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.xtext.util; bundle-version="2.25.0.v20210301-0843"
              org.eclipse.xtext.util [1881]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.google.guava; bundle-version="[30.1.0,31.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.google.guava; bundle-version="30.1.0.v20221112-0806"
                     com.google.guava [49]
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.google.errorprone.annotations; version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.google.errorprone.annotations.concurrent; version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.crypto; version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.crypto.spec; version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual; version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.log4j; version="1.2.15"
                  -> Export-Package: org.apache.log4j; bundle-symbolic-name="org.apache.log4j"; bundle-version="1.2.15.v201012070815"; version="1.2.15"
                     org.apache.log4j [248]
                       No resolution report for the bundle.                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.xtend.lib
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.xtend.lib; bundle-version="2.36.0.v20240825-0714"
                     org.eclipse.xtend.lib [1848]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.xtend.lib.macro; bundle-version="2.36.0"; visibility:="reexport"
                         -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.xtend.lib.macro; bundle-version="2.36.0.v20240825-0714"
                            org.eclipse.xtend.lib.macro [1849]
                              No resolution report for the bundle.         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.log4j; version="1.2.15"
           -> Export-Package: org.apache.log4j; bundle-symbolic-name="org.apache.log4j"; bundle-version="1.2.15.v201012070815"; version="1.2.15"
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.objectweb.asm; bundle-version="[9.1.0,9.2.0)"; resolution:="optional"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.objectweb.asm; bundle-version="9.1.0.v20210209-1849"
              org.objectweb.asm [2054]
                No resolution report for the bundle.         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.xtend.lib; resolution:="optional"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.xtend.lib; bundle-version="2.36.0.v20240825-0714"
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.log4j
    -> Export-Package: org.apache.log4j; bundle-symbolic-name="org.apache.log4j"; bundle-version="1.2.15.v201012070815"; version="1.2.15"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.xtext.util
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.xtext.util; bundle-version="2.25.0.v20210301-0843"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.xtend.lib
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.xtend.lib; bundle-version="2.36.0.v20240825-0714"
  Bundle was not resolved because of a uses constraint violation.
  org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource org.eclipse.cbi.targetplatform [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.1.0.202409011232"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.cbi.targetplatform"; singleton:="true"] because it is exposed to package 'com.google.common.util.concurrent.internal' from resources com.google.guava [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="30.1.0.v20221112-0806"; osgi.identity="com.google.guava"] and com.google.guava.failureaccess [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.0.2"; osgi.identity="com.google.guava.failureaccess"] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  org.eclipse.cbi.targetplatform [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.1.0.202409011232"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.cbi.targetplatform"; singleton:="true"]
    require: (osgi.wiring.bundle=org.eclipse.xtext)
     |
    provide: osgi.wiring.bundle: org.eclipse.xtext
  com.google.guava [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="30.1.0.v20221112-0806"; osgi.identity="com.google.guava"]

Chain 2:
  org.eclipse.cbi.targetplatform [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.1.0.202409011232"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.cbi.targetplatform"; singleton:="true"]
    require: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib)(bundle-version>=2.14.0))
     |
    provide: osgi.wiring.bundle; bundle-version:Version="2.37.0.v20241119-0857"; osgi.wiring.bundle="org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib"
  com.google.guava [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="33.3.1.jre"; osgi.identity="com.google.guava"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.util.concurrent.internal)(&(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: com.google.common.util.concurrent.internal
  com.google.guava.failureaccess [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.0.2"; osgi.identity="com.google.guava.failureaccess"]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:493)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:2102)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2093)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:2033)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1996)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1912)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:341)

Is anyone able to explain what is going awry here, and guide me as to how to fix it, without doing a complete rebuild of Eclipse?

The log should tell the exact root cause for Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.cbi.targetplatform. Please include many more lines from the beginning of the log in your question. Do you have additional plugins installed? If yes, which? You use Java 21 installed on your system to run the Eclipse IDE. If you also updated Java, this might be the reason. Better use the Java included in Eclipse.

I hadn't updated Java recently (last updated June 13 2024 to 21.0.3.0). I updated Eclipse two days ago, and whereas it started and ran fine before, now it doesn't. I will try forcing it to use Temurin, and see if that makes a difference. I have edited my original post to contain the complete text of the entry in the log.

Switching to Temurin (java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium) 21.0.3 did not change anything.

The Java vendor should not matter, but the version or whether it is installed on your system or part of Eclipse. The strange thing is that there are unresolved requirements, which will be checked before installing or updating and prevent installing or updating. Is this now the complete first log !ENTRY with all Chains? Did you install all available updates or only some? Do you have additional plugins installed? Did you installed something via dropins folder?

The Temurin version was installed with the last eclipse install (2024-09). The edit was to include the complete first log !ENTRY, including both chains. I'd appreciate someone with more skill in this area parsing what went wrong. I have lots of plugins, but nothing installed via the dropins folder (at least there is nothing there currently, and the modification time on the folder is mid August).

If I read the log correctly, com.google.guava is required by a plugin in both versions 30.1.0.v20221112-0806 (see chain 1) and 33.3.1.jre (see chain 2). Eclipse 2024-12 contains com.google.guava 33.3.1.jre. It looks like not everything has been updated. Another Help > Check for Updates might help. But it is unclear how you got into this invalid state. There are checks before an update that should prevent this. You have org.eclipse.xtext 2.25.0.v20210301-0843 instead of 2.37.0.v20241119-0857 for reasons not known by me.

Thank you for that. I'll take it from that that I have no choice but to start again from scratch. I'd run Help > Check for Updates, but I don't get a window. Is there any way to run it from the Console?

It might take a while. The progress will be shown in the status line. If it takes too long, deactivate unavailable updates sites in the preferences Update/Install > Available Software Sites. If checking for updates fails, see error log. You can also run it from the command line, but this should not make a difference. In Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details you can revert your installation or update or uninstall specific features.
